# sliding the divs according to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a page here.

http://www.kharota.com/cantsay/index.html

What I wanted was to div slide up and down as url changes for example index.html#thisweek will slide the div which contains data of this week. Sometimes it works sometimes its not. I am big confused there is no error but still not working. The code is following

```
var loc = window.location.href;
if(loc.indexOf( '#' ) >= 0 ) {
   var  hash = loc.substr( loc.indexOf('#') + 1 );
}else{

    var hash = "";
}

if(!hash){
$("#ca").slideDown("fast");     


  }else{




 switch(hash){

     case "iwantagig":
         $("#cd").slideDown("fast");
         $("#ca").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cb").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cc").slideUp("fast");


         break;


     case "jointhecrew":

         $("#cc").slideDown("fast");
         $("#ca").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cb").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cd").slideUp("fast");

         break;


     case "birthdayGuestlist":

         $("#cb").slideDown("fast");
         $("#ca").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cc").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cd").slideUp("fast");

         break;

     case "thisweek":

         $("#ca").slideDown("fast");
         $("#cb").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cc").slideUp("fast");
         $("#cd").slideUp("fast");

         break;



 }
 }
```

The page is here. I would be thankful if someone help.

http://www.kharota.com/cantsay/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.change-page').click(function(){        
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        if(hash) {
            $('.slider').slideUp("fast");
            $('.' + hash).slideDown("fast");
            // where '.' + hash are your page divs which must have the class slider and classes like  jointhecrew, iwantgag etc
        } else {
            $("#ca").slideDown("fast"); 
        }
    });
});
```

I can't test it but I hope this will work for you

Comment: the strangest thing is i have to reload the page for detecting hash. why a page doesnt detect hash without reloading?

Comment: even if you use my code? my code should replace the hash when you clicked on other a.change-page link